# Installing Keyrock on Fiware in my Virtual Machine

Tags: python, fiware

I want install keyrock and I follow [these steps](http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin_guide.html),
but in the step three, when I write in the console:

```
sudo python tools/install_venv.py
```

Console shows me the next fail:

[image]

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Please post your error stacktrace here.

Comment: Screenshots, particularly uncuttent screenshots, show only that you are absolutely not interested in making your question usable. I initiate the closure of your question on the reason of lack of own research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic in the lack of own effort.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, at a first moment, use a container instead of a VM?

Follow the [instructions in the official documentation](http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#docker) or this tutorial about how to integrate Orion Context Broker, Keyrock IdM and Wilma:

https://www.slideshare.net/daltoncezane/integrating-fiware-orion-keyrock-and-wilma

I hope it can help.